# Как открыть доступ к БД в MySQL на другом компьютере?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, unity3d, localhost

Здравствуйте! Сейчас я пишу небольшую программу в Unity, чтобы она считывала и выдавала данные из БД MySQL. Я только начала программировать, поэтому проект для многих скорее всего покажется очень легким, но у меня возникла проблема. В Editor у Unity все работает замечательно, но только на том компьютере, на котором находится моя БД. В принципе, это логично, ведь мой код подключается к БД через localhost, но какие настройки мне нужно предпринять, чтобы БД читалась с другого компьютера, на котором моей БД нет? я понимаю, что скорее всего придется подключать какой-то экстерный сервер (вроде посредника), но все-таки может есть какой-то другой путь?
Заранее большое спасибо за ваши ответы!

Comment: @Mark Shevchenko: большое спасибо за ваш ответ! что-то подобное я уже видела на англоязычном стоке. проблема теперь в следующем: у меня нет в my.ini строки "bind-address"... могу ли я ее просто вручную прописать и закоменнтить? есть ли в этом вообще смысл?

Comment: вы не совсем в правильном месте уточнили свой вопрос. Отвечу Вам в комментарии, но ваш вопрос будет удалён чуть позже. Если у вас нет строки **bind-address**, значит, дело не в ней. Дайте права на таблицы пользователю **username@%** вмето **username@localhost**.

Answer (score 2):

> но какие настройки мне нужно предпринять, чтобы БД читалась с другого компьютера, на котором моей БД нет?

Насколько я понял - у Вас [толстый клиент](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82). А в этом случае если приложение будет работать в локальной сети - укажите вместо `localhost` IP адрес или имя машины где будет развернута база. 
Если нужно чтобы приложение использовали из вне - нужно использовать сервер/компьютер работающий 24/7 и соответственно нужно указывать их параметры.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь есть два подводных камня. Во-первых, MySQL может прослушивать только некоторые IP-адреса (настройка [bind-address](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ipv6-server-config.html)).

Скорее всего, дело не в ней, но проверить надо. Если там прописано **127.0.0.1**, то подключиться к MySQL можно только с того же компьютера. Чтобы разрешить все подключения, укажите строку **0.0.0.0** в качестве значения.

Во-вторых, разрешения на работу с базой выдаются в MySQL для пары пользователь/пароль.

Вместо

```
GRANT ALL ON db1.* TO 'username'@'localhost';
```

используйте

```
GRANT ALL ON db1.* TO 'username'@'%';
```

Здесь `'username'` это имя пользователя, с которым вы подключаетесь к MySQL.

[Подробности](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html).